# Is it not a good practice to handle runtime exceptions in the code?

Tags: java, exceptions

I am working on a Java application, and I see that Run time exceptions are handled in many places. For example,

```
try {
    // do something
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    return null;
}
```

My questions is, when is it a good practice to handle Runtime exceptions? When should exceptions be left unhandled?

Comment: -1: There's no single answer to a question this broad and vague.  It's impossible to provide a single answer to a question so unfocused as this.  This question is awful.  Please provide **specific** examples of where you have doubts.

Comment: @S.Lott I kind of disagree in this case as it seems there is a subset of programmers that have it in their head that this is the case with no "Good" Rationality.

Comment: @Chad: "this is the case with no "Good" Rationality".  That may be true.  But the only possible answer has to be "it depends".  Therefore, the question seems faulty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends.

For example, `Integer#parseInt` throws `NumberFormatException` (which is a RTE) if the provided string can't be parsed. But surely you don't want your app to crash just because the user wrote "x" to a text field that was for integers? And how do you know whether the string can be parsed, unless you try to parse it first? So in this case, the RTE is just an error signal that should cause some kind of error message. One could argue that it *should* be a checked exception, but what can you do - it isn't.

Comment: I agree with "It depends", but your parsing example seems to be rather a case of bad API design. `Integer#parseInt` should really return a `Maybe<Integer>` instead and not throw any exception at all.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: I agree that it's bad API design, but it's the real world we have to deal with. How to properly handle throwables / return values depends on how the world *actually* works, not on how it optimally *should* work :-)

Comment: The point here is, you can do something meaningful for an anticipated condition (user input not integer). Just swallowing NPE is bad style and will just cover up existing programming errors.

Answer (score 7):

NullPointerExceptions are usually the sign of a missing null check. So, instead of catching it like this, you should add the apropriate null check to be sure to not throw the exception.

But sometimes, it is appropiate to handle RunTimeExceptions. For example, when you cannot modify the code to add the null check at the appropriate place, or when the exception is something other than a NullPointerException.

Your example of handling exceptions is terrible. Doing so, you lose the stack trace and precise information about the problem. And you are actually not solving it as you will probably trigger another NullPointerException in a different place, and get misleading information about what happened and how to solve it.

Comment: I'd like to add that a null check is a better decision performance-wise.

Comment: ...still, if you're making dozens of allocations that "should never fail" around one place, adding null checks for each of them may ridiculously obfuscate the code. A catch-all exception (that WILL handle the situation gracefully, not just `return null;`) will be a better solution.

Comment: You probably are confusing java with something else (C++ for exemple). When an allocation fails, you get an OutOfMemoryError or something similar, never a null pointer. Hidding a null return instead of an exception is hidding the error waiting for the code to explode somewhere else.

Comment: `new` throws `std::bad_alloc` in C++.

Comment: Assuming that the new operator isn't overloaded, which is common practice. In C++, anything can happen ;) But OK, let's say C's malloc. The important point was that you never got that in java.

Comment: @deadalnix: If an allocation fails due to a lack of memory, one will get an exception rather than a null pointer.  On the other hand, it's not hard to imagine a `get next item` method which will either return a newly-constructed item or `null` if there isn't one (not unreasonable, if the API will frequently be called by code which will e.g. read data as long as it's available).  Ideally, there would be two API functions--one of which would throw an exception if no data exists and one which would simply return null, but if all one has is the "null if no data" method...

Comment: ...I would suggest that it may be cleaner to have code which expects that data should exist to simply read data and try to use it, than add testing code after every single read.  A big part of the purpose of exceptions, after all, is to avoid bogging down the main-line code with error trapping.  If all the data was read successfully, things will work.  If not, the calling code should get an exception conveying that the data couldn't be read, and the calling code should act upon that information as it sees fit.

Comment: @supercat you are right with C++ and allocation, but this is kind of OT. You example of the API returning null on getNextItem is great. This is an appropriate use of null. In fact, this is an implicit contract between the caller and the callee. If you plan to store the value instead of reading it, you'd better assert that the contract is respected, otherwise, you'll find out that a problem occur much later. If you plan to consume the data immediately, no need to add checks, you are right.

Comment: @deadalnix: Thinking about it, if there were a good efficient way of defining a local shorthand for a batch of code (e.g. `err`), perhaps a good approach would be `var1 = thing.get_data() ?? err(); var2 = thing.get_data() ?? err();` etc.  If one had to write out `throw new EndOfFileException(...)`, that would clutter up the code a bit much.  One could define `err()` as a closure, but that would require creating a closure and delegate every time through even in the case where everything works normally.

Comment: I would argue NullPointerExceptions do *not* typically indicate that there should be a null check, but instead indicate that the caller made a mistake. Furthermore, unlike what Mahmoud Hossam said, null checks are *slower* in the normal case that the reference is non-null. If the case that the reference is null is an error, I would simply let the NPE occur unless a null check would provide a clearer message to a programmer mistakenly passing null, in which case the null check should also throw a NPE. OTOH if the reference can legitimately be null, a null check may be needed for correctness.

Answer (score 4):

I handle Expected exceptions where I expect them.  (Like DB read/write errors).  Unexpected exceptions I bubble up.  Somewhere else may be expecting the exception and have the logic for it.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions should be just that.. exceptions.  Best practice when using exceptions is to use them to cover the situation in which something contrary to what you would expect to happen happens.  The classic example is the FileNotFoundException which gets thrown when a file simply isn't there.  If you're testing the existence of the file, then you use File.exists() since you're simply prodding with a 10 foot stick to see if you hit something.

You could technically accomplish the same results by surrounding it in a try catch and using the file as if it existed, but A) exceptions are generally costly resource-wise and B) programmers are going to assume you meant the file to exist if it was in a try catch, which adds to the overall confusion of a program.

There are many situations in which I'll write a method which fetches some value from a database.  A thousand things could go wrong, and seeing how I only need one small piece of information, it's inconvenient to surround the call with a try catch list that contains 5 various exceptions.  So, I'll catch exceptions in the fetch method.  If something goes wrong, I take whatever appropriate action to close the database connection or whatnot in the finally clause and return null.  This is good practice not only because it simplifies your code but also because "null" sends the same message you could have gotten from an exception.. that something didn't go as planned.  Manage exception specifics in the fetch method, but manage what to do when things don't go as planned in the receiving end by checking to see if the result was null.

For example:

```
Integer getUserCount() {
   Integer result = null;
   try {
      // Attempt to open database and retrieve data
   } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      logger.error("Got a watch?");
   } catch (MissingDatabaseException e) {
      logger.error("What are you smoking?");
   } catch (PermissionsToReadException e) {
      logger.error("Did you *really* think you were getting away with that?");
   } catch (PressedSendButtonToHardException e) {
      logger.error("Seriously.. just back away from the computer... slowly..");
   } catch (WTFException e) {
      logger.error("You're on your own with this one.. I don't even know what happened..");
   } finally {
      // Close connections and whatnot
   }
   return result;
}

void doStuff() {
   Integer result = getUserCount();
   if(result != null) {
       // Went as planned..
   }
}
```

Comment: If you use File.exists() and rely on the result, a race condition could happen if the file is deleted right between File.exists() and File.open(). If this triggers a security-critical bug, an attacker could cause this condition on purpose. Because of this, it's sometimes better to keep the operation atomic, i.e. try it and catch the exception.

Comment: Also, there are files that must exist for the running of the application. Those would be exceptional conditions. If there's a file that you must have in order for the application to function, then there's no reason not to read from it and then handle the exception for the exceptional case. I believe it makes the intent more clear.

Comment: This a bad decision to return null. It will result in NullPointerException at some point and will be really hard to debug what went wrong. Because somebody WILL at some point forget the null check.

Comment: @deadalnix: I could argue that you could just as easily forget to surround with a try-catch otherwise.  Difference is a matter of style, not functionality.

Comment: @ammoQ: I disagree.  I think you should use File.exists() and under the rare circumstance that it gets deleted before you use it, an exception is more than appropriate.  The difference is where you keep your catch.  Simply have a blanket exception catcher for unanticipated errors in order to log and report it.

Comment: @Neil The difference isn't just style. It is functionnality, not for the user, but for the developper. In one case, you have all informations to solve the problem : the stack trace and the error message. If you catch that exception, the stack trace and the error message will be lost forever. And if you don't solve the problem, you'll face nullpointerexception anyway. So, when debugging, instead of getting all informations, you get an anonymous message and have a detective job to do, which is very boring and time consuming.

Comment: @deadalnix: Look up log4j.  You can log a message alongside the exception itself and it will print its message and stack trace.  Unexpected exceptions shouldn't go unnoticed.  It's one thing if you expect an exception, as it should be caught and handled accordingly.  Though unexpected exceptions should be caught only to be rethrown (idea being that whoever called your method might know more than you why the error happened).  A blanket try catch should exist in the base frame of your program only to log errors that weren't anticipated in any section of your program.

Comment: This is not what you wrote as sample code in your answer. In your sample code, you are just waiting for your program to crach and them look up in bunch of logs for hours because you have no clue what to look for.

Comment: @deadalnix:  Expected exceptions are caught and logged.  Note that I didn't catch "Exception" because that falls into the category of unexpected exceptions.  All the caller needs to know is whether or not the result is null or not.  The error is handled if it is expected, and handled further down the line if it's not.

Answer (score -5):

yes you are correct handling run time exceptions is not a good practice.The reason  is that it is considered to costly/ memory intensive.

Comment: Hi prassee, can you elaborate on your answer? One-liners that aren't backed up with facts, references, or experiences aren't very helpful.